# Add UIView over UIImage - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, uiview, uigraphicscontext

I have a UIImage of size 1080x1920, and a UIView of size 375x812.
I want to scale up the view and draw it over the UIImage in the center, in this way:

**Initial phase:**
[image]

**Second Phase:**
[image]

This is the code I implemented to get the UIView over the UIImage scaling it up:

```
let proportionalWidthUpperView = (inImage.size.height * self.view.frame.size.width)/self.view.frame.size.height
    let differenceWidth = inImage.size.width - proportionalWidthUpperView
    
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(inImage.size)
    let rect = CGRect(x: differenceWidth/2, y: 0, width: inImage.size.width-(differenceWidth), height: inImage.size.height)
    inImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: inImage.size.width, height: inImage.size.height))
    imageFromUpperView?.draw(in: rect)
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    return result!
```

Scaling the view up making It match the UIImage height, I retrieve the difference in width and I add it to the left and right of the rect.

This method works perfectly on iPhones but using it on iPads with bigger view frame I get the view scaled it up, do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add UIView as subview to UIImageView and you can apply transformations and scaling and rest the frame of UIView added.

Hope this will simplify and help.